# Is there a way to trigger the custom fallback intent instead of the default fallback?

Tags: dialogflow-es

[image: intents]
In Dialogflow-es, I want to trigger the Custom fallback intent ("Want an appointment-service-fallback") anytime the user doesn't trigger the other intent ("Want an appointment - service-hairdressor") with the training phrases.

However, I'm not sure how to set it up and I keep triggering the default fallback intent.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the Intents setup are as Followup Intents, meaning they will only be matched in the turn (or two) after the Intent they're following up on has matched.

So in your illustration, in order for the "service-Fallback" intent to be triggered, the conversation must have:

1. Matched the "want an appointment" Intent by something the user said
2. *Then* matched the "service" Intent on the next exchange with what the user said
3. And *then*, when the user said something else, it can't have matched the hairdresser phrase

So unless you have gotten to that point in the conversation, you won't end up triggering the "service-Fallback" intent.